# Unable to read JSON body from the request object in Java servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

I have created a java servlet that accepts POST requests. In the body of POST request there is a JSON payload.
The Request looks like this -
[image]

In the servlet I am trying to get the JSON payload and print it -

```
StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = null;
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = slingRequest.getReader();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    jb.append(line);
            } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject =  HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());
                PrintWriter pw = slingResponse.getWriter();
                pw.println(jsonObject);
                pw.close();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // crash and burn
                throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON request string");
            }
```

The output is as follows -

```
{"{        \"metadata\"":"{            \"id\": \"a@A.com\",            \"subscription-pref\": \"Subs\",            \"category\": \"COURSE\",            \"isSubscribed\": true,            \"source\": \"form\"        }    }}","Request-URI":"subscription","Method":"{","HTTP-Version":":"}
```

Please note that the `subscription` node doesnt exist in the output. Instead its displayed as a value for `Request-URI`. Why am I getting these additional values like `Request-URI` and `HTTP-Version`. Why is the `subscription` node missing? I just want to read the JSON payload

Comment: It seems that all lines include ":" are treated as HTTP response header, right?

Comment: Maybe. Any solution for this?

Comment: You should learn more details about that response class behaviors. You'd better put your JSON data into response-body.

Comment: im trying to read the data from "request" object.

Comment: I believe reading data was done without problems. Your problem about "The output" which you get here is a result of processing in PrintWriter instance, which was from slingResponse.getWriter(), I suppose. If you want to check whether the reading result was correct or not, how about put that data to System.out (which would not modify your string to any other format) first?

Comment: what does `slingRequest` has in it ?